# How to make a list view associate with other view?

Tags: listview, android-layout

here is one question, how to make a listview shown with other view in single activity? Below are the layout and code files, it displays nothing wrong on Eclipse but force closed by android VM

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:layout_height="0dip"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="select" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="select2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

code part

```
public abstract class firstActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

Button Button1;
Button Button2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, webname));


    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public  void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });
}

static final String[] webname = new String[] {
    "http://www.YYYYYY.com","http://www.XXXXXX.com"
};
```

Thanks for advance

Here is the R.layout.list_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="12sp" >
```

Is it something wrong with the ListAdapter? Sorry I am a newbie, not much knowledge got.

Comment: Could you show the content of the LogCat? What is `R.layout.list_item`? If you want to have a particular layout for each row of the listView, you have to write a customAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have defined your class as `abstract`. 
An abstract class lets you put the common method names in one abstract class without having to write the implementation code. Classes that contain abstract methods, are called abstract classes.
See here for the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).
Delete that abstract and your code will run.

Comment: Here comes another problem:"The type firstActivity must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)" by Eclispe. Is it anything I need to implement to the listview part? Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to delete the `implements OnItemClickListener`, you have already set the `onItemClickListener` with that new within the `setOnItemClickListener`.